# font-weight is not working properly?

Tags: css, fonts

http://www.i3physics.com/blog/2010/07/dsfsdf/

Here is an example.

The part where it said "PHP" (the right top corner) remained as slim as it was.
here is part of the css code

```
.wp_syntax_lang {
  background-color:#3c3c3c;
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  padding:1px 10px 3px;
  color:#ddd; font-size:9px; font-weight:800;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:5px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
  border-radius-bottomleft:5px;
}
```

I tried bold, bolder, 700, 800, 900 and is not working under FF.

Comment: You didn't ask, but the layout is extremely tight and trying to cram a 36px h1 into a 436px wide #header causes "Blo/g" to wrap at the slash at any zoom factor (linux chrome).

Comment: You've also got a couple syntax errors and a markup error: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.i3physics.com/blog/2010/07/dsfsdf/&charset=(detect+automatically)&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: Thank you msw. I will work on those when I have the time :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Its because the font size (9px) is too small to display bold. Try 11px or more and it works fine.

Answer (score 56):

`font-weight` can fail to work if the font you are using does not have those weights in existence – you will often hit this when embedding custom fonts. In those cases the browser will likely round the number to the closest weight that it does have available.

For example, if I embed the following font...

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Nexa";
    src: url("Nexa-Regular.ttf") format("truetype");
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Then I will not be able to use anything other than a weight of 400. All other weights will revert to 400.

If you want additional weights, you need to specify them in separate `@font-face` declarations with those additional weights, like this.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Nexa";
    src: url("Nexa-Light.ttf") format("truetype");
    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Nexa";
    src: url("Nexa-Regular.ttf") format("truetype");
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Nexa";
    src: url("Nexa-Bold.ttf") format("truetype");
    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Usually each weight will have a separate font file the browser will need to download, unless you're using variable width fonts.

Comment: how to declare multiple font weights under one font family. ?

Comment: @DularaMalindu You need to duplicate the whole `@font-face {...}` block, but in the new copy change the weight and URL to the font file (as usually each weight will be in a separate file). Does that make sense?

Comment: I've updated the answer above to demonstrate multiple declarations

Answer (score 32):

Most browsers don't fully support the numerical values for `font-weight`.  [Here's a good article about the problem](http://www.clagnut.com/blog/2228/), and even tough it's a little old, it does seem to be correct.

If you need something bolder then you might want to try using a different font that's bolder than your existing one.  Naturally, you could probably adjust the font size for a similar effect.

Comment: A note from the future: I don't think this applies anymore. At least, numeric values seems to be pretty common practice at this point.

Answer (score 30):

If you're importing a Google font, you need to ensure you've specified all the weights that you would like to use.

In my case, I was using Google's Roboto font. I had to import it with several different weights, like this:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono|Roboto+Slab|Roboto:300,400,500,700" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Remember that each additional weight increases the amount of data each visitor needs to download, and can slow down the loading of your page, so only use what's necessary.

Comment: This worked great for me since I was also using google fonts! Thanks

Comment: Importing the correct weights was the key for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

i was also facing the same issue, I resolved it by after selecting the Google's font that i was using, then I clicked on (Family-Selected) minimized tab and then clicked on "CUSTOMIZE" button.
Then I selected the font weights that I want and then embedded the updated link in my html..

Answer (score 1):

I removed the `text-transform: uppercase;` and then set it to `bold`/`bolder`, and this seemed to work.

Answer (score 1):

For me the bold work when I change the font style from   `font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;` to `Arial`