# How do I define font-weight in CSS?

Tags: css

I need the font to be thicker than normal, but thinner than bold.

How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 5):

The css `font-weight` property is what you want, but not all fonts support it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/font-weight

Comment: The key phrase is "not all *fonts* support it." CSS applies a heuristic from the weight you provide to one of the versions provided by the font. A good explanation is http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-boldness. In other words, unless the font provides a "Light Bold" flavor, you are out of luck.

Answer (score 2):

Not all browsers support this feature. It's either bold or not bold.

See: http://clagnut.com/blog/2228/

Comment: I don't know of any browser that reliably supports this feature.

Comment: Not even Chrome supports this yet, and that's saying something.

Comment: I think its not that browsers don't support it, but that *fonts* don't support it.

Comment: When clagnut.com/blog/2228 was written apparently only Firefox 3 for Mac supported intermediate font weights. However Firefox 4 for Windows should support intermediate font weights if it thinks it's safe to use DirectWrite on your OS and graphics adapter.

Answer (score 1):

Use a number from 100-900. 400 is normal, and 700 is bold.

```
p.NotAsThickAsBold { font-weight: 500 }
```

[W3.org - Font Weight](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/fonts.html#font-boldness)

Comment: I've tried that. It doesn't work.
I tested it in several browsers - no result.

Comment: please don't link w3schools... they are being shunned. (not complying to standards and whatnot: [w3fools](http://w3fools.com/))

Comment: How large is your text size? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367589/font-weight-is-not-working-properly#3367612

Comment: Pull the ref out before you get downvoted 100 times like I did the last time I linked to w3schools...

Comment: @Joseph - Thank you so much for that link. I was unaware of the issues they have. I will update my post.

Comment: @MikeKusold np :) someone else on SO brought it to my attention too.

Comment: @vlevsha, try increasing the size temporarily to see if it applies the weight. If not, then you might need to use another font or replace it with an image to get the result you desire.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/font-weight

You can specify it using a number:

```
.class-name {
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

Also, from the MDN reference....

> 100-500 are normal, and 600-900 are bold

Answer (score 0):

```
font-weight:bold;
font-weight:normal;
```